# How can I remove the trailing zeros from this code in output in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list, python-3.8

I wrote this code and now I want to remove the trailing zeros from the output in Python

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[18, 16.25, 14, 17], [12, 15, 13, 15], [19, 20, 18, 17]]
y = pd.DataFrame(
    data, 
    index=["Ali", "Mohammad", "Reza"],
    columns=["Physics", "Shimi", "Riazi", "Adabiat"])
```

`y` table looks after calling `print(y)` like:

```
          Physics  Shimi  Riazi  Adabiat
Ali            18  16.25     14       17
Mohammad       12  15.00     13       15
Reza           19  20.00     18       17
```

I just want to remove the trailing zeros for 15.00 and 20.00 only.

Comment: Can I ask you why you want to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *applymap* with lambda function to check is numeric and then convert it to string and remove trailing zeros using rstrip

```
y = y.applymap(lambda x: str(x).rstrip('0').rstrip('.') if (isinstance(x, (int, float)) and '.' in str(x)) else x)
print(y)
```